# How to retrieve data from a range in ADODB?

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have 2 worksheets, trying to make a db connection from data worksheets and paste the values as a summary in the summary worksheet by using a simple SELECT statement.
My query clause works fine if I'm not specifying the dimension of the range in the FROM clause when I have to do that because the headers in the data worksheet start from cell C11 until CR200000.
Is there a way to ensure that the record set reads the data until the bottom line?

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim Conn, Rcs As Object, sql As String

Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With Conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0"";"
    .Open
     End With
     
     'This works because FROM Clause with no range in Data worksheet
     sql = "TRANSFORM SUM(T1.[Grand Total]) " & _
           "SELECT T1.[Region],T1.[Sub Region],T1.[OU] " & _
           ",T1.[Customer Number],T1.[Customer Name] " & _
           "FROM [Data$C11:CR] T1 " & _
           "WHERE NOT T1.[Region] IN ('Bottom') " & _
           "GROUP BY T1.[Customer Number] " & _
           "PIVOT T1.[Aging Buckets]"
     
     
    'This does not work because FROM Clause specify a range [Data$C11:CR200000]
    sql = "TRANSFORM SUM(T1.[Grand Total]) " & _
           "SELECT T1.[Region],T1.[Sub Region],T1.[OU] " & _
           ",T1.[Customer Number],T1.[Customer Name] " & _
           "FROM [Data$C11:CR200000] T1 " & _
           "WHERE NOT T1.[Region] IN ('Bottom') " & _
           "GROUP BY T1.[Customer Number] " & _
           "PIVOT T1.[Aging Buckets]"
           

     Set Rcs = Conn.Execute(sql)
 
       If Not Rcs.BOF And Not Rcs.EOF Then
        Sheets("Summary").Cells(5, 2).CopyFromRecordset Rcs
            End If

   Rcs. Close
   Conn.Close
Set Rcs = Nothing
Set Conn = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I understand where is the problem with the first SQL... Doesn't the return start from the 11th row? Doesn't it return up to the last filled range (row 200000)?

Comment: first sql works but it dose not go all the way to CR200000 and returns 12000 rows when i meant to get 19000 if it went all the way down. the 2nd sql does not work and debugs with not recognising the [Data$C11:CR200000]